# ManagementObjectSearcher Get() method returns no results

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm trying to terminate a process on a remote machine with WMI / C# on .NET 4.5. In the code below, when the Get method is called on the ManagementObjectSearcher instance nothing is returned, so the line inside the foreach is not reached. The ManagementScope is connected and the query variable contains the name of the process for termination.
Thx for any help.

```
try
        {
            ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
            ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", NetworkName), connOptions);
            manScope.Connect();
            var query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_process where name = '" + ProcessName + "'");

            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(manScope, query))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
                {
                    process.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException err)
        {
            //Do something with error message here
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Count` property to check, whether it contains *any* record. That is, `if(searcher.Get().count == 0)` returns `true`, means *no record* is present.

Comment: Thanks, the Count property returned 0 and that showed me that in fact the query results are null. I guess in my code as soon as var query = new SelectQuery(...) is hit, the query executes against the local machine. In any case I've dropped the query variable, moved the new SelectQuery(...) declaration into the ManagementObjectSearcher constructor and it's working. Yay! Thanks for pointing me in right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined in my comment above, for completeness here's the code with my changes that are as follows.

```
        try
        {
            ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
            ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", NetworkName), connOptions);
            manScope.Connect();
            ProcessName = ProcessName + ".exe";

            using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(manScope, new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Process where Name = '" + ProcessName + "'")))
            {
                foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
                {
                    process.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ManagementException err)
        {
            //Do something with error message here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was unable to receive CPU utilization value remotely using WMI query:

```
SELECT PercentProcessorTime FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor WHERE Name='_Total'
```

I changed project build platform target from **Any CPU** to **x64** to match my system bitness, and problem was solved. Another way is uncheck **Prefer 32-bit** checkbox when **Any CPU** is selected.